# Why is Stack Overflow trying to rick roll me?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I saw an add for apptivate.ms this morning - clicked it - and followed it to the apptivate.ms domain. I checked the WHOIS for the domain and it owned by Stack Exchange, Inc. I also thought it was interesting that the advertising link URL embedded a few things about my account on SO - rough rep count, some tag stuff, etc.

A few "failed" password attempts led me to a rather popular YouTube video of a pop star near and dear to our hearts: Mr. Rick Astley.

I am guessing this is some sort of game or (putting on my evil hat) a ploy by the SE team to gather passwords for some nefarious reason? Nerd fodder!

Comment: Maybe they're going all Valve on us? There's a code hidden in one of the off-topic questions on MSO which leads to a newly created user-account on SO which will give us the possibility to gain the password necessary...and then there will be cake!

Comment: So when you see a password field on a site you know you haven't registered for, your first instinct is to type in a few passwords? :)

Comment: Absolutely. They don't call me Little Bobby Tables for no reason... http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Goyuix Admitting [being a sockpuppet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/334849/littlebobbytables), are we? :)

Comment: For the record, the password was "patent pending".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for clicking!

We are in the process of launching a contest campaign for Microsoft Windows 8, but the ads were started too soon. We have disabled them for now.

The next time you see an Apptivate ad on the site, the campaign will be live and there will be no password.

Edited: The campaign is now live. You can read more about it at our blog: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/ or by visiting the [site](http://apptivate.ms). Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find anything in the blog. Can you post direct link to the relevant blog post?

Comment: The blog post is: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/apptivate-ms-a-windows-8-app-development-contest/

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the advertisement went live a little early - visiting the [site](http://apptivate.ms/) now shows some actual content:

> Apptivate.MS is a Windows 8 App Development Contest sponsored by Microsoft.
>
> Get your product into the hands of millions of consumers as soon as Windows 8 is released.
>
> Earn amazing prizes along the way, including $5,000 cash, exposure for your app, Windows 8 devices, and more.
>
> Vote and comment on apps, ask and answer Windows 8 questions on Stack Overflow, and earn more chances to win.
>
> For more information, check out the contest!

Comment: Anyhow, it's awesome that I'm the 4th user on the site!