# Why can't I resolve www.apptivate.ms?

Tags: bug, status-completed, apptivate.ms

I am not able to resolve http://www.apptivate.ms/ (Firefox gives me a 404, as does Chrome).
However, http://apptivate.ms/ resolves fine.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

For the record, all of this is a contest campaign for Microsoft Windows 8, launched by Stack Exchange as explained [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/apptivate-ms-a-windows-8-app-development-contest/).

Comment: So? The add works and redirects to apptivate.ms. If any problem it would be of Microsoft webhosting

Comment: Great tool for testing if these issues are limited only to you or are affecting everyone - http://www.isup.me/

Comment: For everyone voting to close as off topic, apptivate.ms _is_ part of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Repro on my end and on http://www.isup.me/http://www.apptivate.ms

Comment: @Yannis is (as usual :)) [correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148454/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-rick-roll-me).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3708/why-was-a-question-i-answered-automatically-deleted#comment7166_3710 ;P

Comment: Wait, people click on ads?

Comment: @Yannis I swear I did not see that before! :D

Comment: TIL Microsoft uses domain hacks.

Comment: juergen, the ad was pointing to a non working url (since it had the www, and it was not working this morning)
lix and shawn, the site was technically up, since it was giving a 404 error, so your tool is useless in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Alright; the server responds to `www.` now (and redirects to the correct domain).

Please let us know where you saw that link to the wrong domain, so we can fix that. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect someone saw the URL, manually entered it and assumed it needed or could use www

Comment: It wasn't working this morning, it is working now. No I didn't entered the www manually, and the add had the "wrong" url. I did some googling, and found it was working with out the www

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni Okay then, thanks for the report!