# WIP Demo outside the store

Tags: support, windows-8, apptivate.ms

I'm building an HTML5 game for [apptivate](http://apptivate.ms/) but since I'd rather show a live work in progress than a plain video (+ it saves me time), do you know if providing a pre-release demo collides with any of the guidelines since it hasn't been published on the Windows Store yet?

Note I know that some of the WinJS features won't work. You could call it a "core demo" without the WinJS features.

Comment: To potential closers: This question is about the [Apptivate contest](http://apptivate.ms/), it's not off-topic.

Comment: + it was suggested on the normal stack overflow to post this stuff here as seen on [here]/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789475/do-i-need-to-pay-for-windows-8-store-before-entering-the-apptivate-ms-contest)

Comment: @PolCPP Stack Overflow is wrong about where things should be migrated like 30% of the time, but yes, it does appear to be on-topic here

Comment: @MichaelMrozek [on topic indeed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150081/why-cant-i-resolve-www-apptivate-ms) :-)

Answer (score 1):

There should be no issue providing a demo of the game prior to having store approval. That said, to be ultimately eligible for the contest, all apps must be approved in the Windows Store with the applicable URL provided.

Per the contest rules at http://apptivate.ms/apps/guidelines:

*Note that you must include the url your app receives in the Windows Store with your final submission in order to be eligible for prizes (by December 6th). While submitting to the Store is not considered a separate phase, consider the time it takes for your app to be accepted to the Store when planning.